# Adding file to git's stage does nothing and cannot be committed

Tags: git

I have gotten myself into a bizarre situation where in one of my branches a web.config file cannot be added to the stage. The output of

```
git add path/to/web.config
git status
```

Is the same as as before the file was added. Web.config appears to require modifications and has not been added to the stage.

Perhaps more interestingly, when I delete the Web.config from the file system and run `git status` I get output that indicates I have **two web.config** files that are ready to be deleted and are not staged.

```
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   deleted: path/to/Web.config
#   deleted: path/to/web.config
```

Note that one has and uppercase W and the other a lowercase w. The file that I removed on the actual file system is an uppercase 'W'.

#### Edit 1

The output of `git ls-files --stage` shows that there are indeed two files that differ by case in the index.

```
100644 63cd5911b9b12bbad559bb69b1b596708b932061 0 path/to/Web.config
100644 d60ab44bb38f05ffce126ddd3c3293b06e6e4096 0 path/to/web.config
```

I output each of these to a file with `git cat-file -p <hash> > <file>` and compared the two files. While the textual content is the same, the uppercase Web.config contains CRLF endings and the lowercase web.config contains lowercase endings.

#### Edit 2

With the file physically deleted from the file system `git reset HEAD` produces this output but the file is not restored on the file system and therefore cannot be added.

```
Unstaged changes after reset
D    path/to/Web.config
D    path/to/web.config
```

I want the file in the working directory to have CRLF as I am working on Windows but I would like for text files to be stored with LF in the internal Git database. So, I assume that would be 63cd591 but I could be off base here.

How do I permanently remove path/to/web.config from the index in this scenario? I am on Windows and cannot have two files on my path that differ only by case.

Comment: Are you using Mac OS X and have two files that differ only in capitalization?  For example foo/bar/web.config and foo/Bar/web.config.

Comment: Can you add the output of `git ls-files --stage`? And if that also has duplicate entries, the output of `git cat-file -p <hash>` where hash is each of the relevant hashes from the output of the ls-files command.

Comment: Is this repeatable? That is, does `git reset HEAD && git add path/to/web.config` put you back in this same situation?

Comment: "How do I permanently remove path/to/web.config from the index in this scenario?". Does `git rm --cached patch/to/web.config` work?

Comment: @CharlesBailey `git rm --cached path/to/web.config --dry-run` would appear to remove the Web.config file, capital.

Comment: So, the next invocation should remove the other capitalization and then you can add back your preferred form of the file.

Comment: @CharlesBailey removing both, committing, and then re-adding the file back in worked. If someone wants to provide an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @RyanTaylor: You can provide your own answer on SO.  Such a well crafted question deserves a well crafted answer ;)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The final solution to this particular problem was to remove both web.config entries from the git cache, commit any changes, and re-add the desired Web.config file back to git.

```
git rm --cached path/to/Web.config
git rm --cached path/to/web.config
git commit -m "Repair confused cache"
git add path/to/Web.config
git commit -m "Add Web.config"
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan, this was just what I needed!

Comment: I got an error when I 'rm on cache', i had to force it with -f to remove it from cache

git rm -f --cached filepath

To avoid error: 
`error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:`

Comment: I have run into this same situation where I add or modify few files and they start showing as both staged and unstaged.  Attempt to stage them with git add then does nothing.  Doing the suggested above did help me however it did not fixed the issue as the situation would come back over and over.  I wonder what is causing this issue?  I am using Mac, git, and also SourceTree.  Both git and SourceTree are shoving same behavior.

Answer (score 17):

Typically when git gets into a confused state, removing and re-adding the file to the cache will fix it:

```
git rm --cached foo
```

It seems the most common way that a file gets in the confused state, is when performing a `mv` from the command line.
I've found that using  `git mv`  instead of `mv` helps to prevent running into this issue. 
http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-mv

Lastly, If you are going to delete a file from a git repository, use `git rm` instead of just `rm`
 [Why use 'git rm' to remove a file instead of 'rm'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434449/why-use-git-rm-to-remove-a-file-instead-of-rm)

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html`

Comment: This is actually a more efficient solution to the problem.