# GitHub for Mac - Staging is not working correctly (Changes not staged for commit)

Tags: git, github, commit

I was using the *GitHub for Mac* application, and as of recently, it's been throwing this error back at me:

---

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory

  modified:   bin/plugin.yml
  modified:   src/plugin.yml

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

  .gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
 (1)
```

---

I have no idea what is doing this, because previously, the program was committing and syncing fine, but now I have to go to the command line and type "`git add .`" and "`git push`" to make it work, so the GitHub app has become completely useless for me.
I would like to keep the app for convenience, but at the moment, it's not looking good.

Comment: Are you the only one working on that GitHub repo? Could it be the result of a `git push --force` by someone else on said GitHub repo?

Comment: I am the only one working on the repo, but I know for a fact that I have done a series of `git push --force` previous to this.

I haven't used `git checkout` yet because I am new to Git in general and I do not understand its use or how to works.

Comment: Can you make sure you `git add` everything, including the `.gitignore`, and `git commit`, and `git push`? (note: if you forget the `git commit` part, it won't work) Then you can try a a fresh git clone and see if the issue persists from GitHub for Mac with that new local clone.

Comment: I have been using `git add .` - will that still work? If it does, I will start doing this now.

Comment: Yes it should work. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190440/6309

Comment: That seems to have did the trick! I was trying to mark your answer as accepted, but I am not seeing where the button is for me to do so next to your comment. I want to make it so others who have this issue can find your helpful comment.

Comment: Sounds great. I have added an answer summarizing those comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct sequence would be:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit .gitignore"
git push
```

(The `commit` step is important if you want to push anything)

Then try a fresh clone and see if GitHub for Mac still complains with that new local repo.

The [OP jflory7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2497452/jflory7) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800085/github-for-mac-staging-is-not-working-correctly-changes-not-staged-for-commit/17804202?noredirect=1#comment26102237_17804202):

> It appears clearing the cache was the best way to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like this was only a temporary fix - I just tried doing it again today and GitHub is still throwing the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @jflory7 does the issue persists with a fresh clone?

Comment: @jflory7 if yes, check the two possible cause of automatic transformation: git config core.autocrlf false, and different cases (as in http://stackoverflow.com/q/17798583/6309, see its comments, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13241590/6309)

Comment: It appears clearing the cache was the best way to fix the issue for me. I'm not sure if this is a permanent fix, but it got it working again for now. I will post back with more details soon.

Comment: @jflory7 Ok. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.