# Removing pycache in git

Tags: python, git, pyc

How can I remove existing and future pycahce files from git repository in Windows? The commands I found online are not working for example when I send the command "`git rm -r --cached __pycache__`" I get the command "`pathspec '__pycache__' did not match any files`".

Comment: yeah, you probably meant `.pycache`, not `pycache`, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's `__pycache__`, not `.pycache`. The OP didn't properly formatted the text so the double underscores changed text to be bold.

Comment: @phd Even after I added .pycache. I get the response "fatal: pathspec '.pycache' did not match any files"

Comment: ah if there's actually double underscores here, dit: good news, the `__pycache__` directory isn't part of your git repo. So you've got nothing to remove from the index.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I wish it was true but __pycache__ folders are there when I search. However, I am not sure what you mean by __pycache__ directory.

Comment: they're there, but not in the git index; they're *untracked*. So it's not `git rm`'s job to delete them. I've answered that before:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git Shell: How can we remove specific file from untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38564613/git-shell-how-can-we-remove-specific-file-from-untracked-files)

Comment: The terms "folder" and "directory" are used interchangeably these days. `__pycache__` is a directory; `__pycache__` is a folder: these mean the same thing. Python creates `__pycache__` directories / folders when loading `.py` files, so that future loading of the same `.py` files goes faster.

Answer (score 0):

The `__pycache__` folders that you are seeing are not in your current and future Git commits.  Because of the way Git works internally—which Git forces you to know, at least if you're going to understand it—*understanding* this is a bit tricky, even once we get past the "directory / folder confusion" we saw in your comments.

The right place to start, I believe, is at the top.  Git isn't *about* **files** (or even files-and-folders / files-and-directories).  Those new to Git see it as storing files, so they think it's about files, but that's just not true.  Or, they note the importance of the ideas behind branches, and think that Git is about branches, and that too is not really true, because people confuse one kind of "branch" (that does matter) with branch *names* (which *don't* matter).  The first thing to know, then, is that **Git is really all about commits**.

This means that you really need to know:

- what a commit is, and
- what a commit does for you

(these two overlap but are not identical).  We won't really cover what a commit *is* here, for space reasons, but let's look at the main thing that one does for you:  **Each commit stores a full snapshot of every file.**

> We now need a small digression into files and folders and how Git and your OS differ in terms of how they *organize* files.  Your computer insists that a *file* has a name like `file.ext` and lives in a *folder* or *directory*—the two terms are interchangeable—such as `to`, which in turn lives in another folder such as `path`.  This produces `path/to/file.ext` or, on Windows, `path\to\file.ext`.
>
> Git, by contrast, has only *files*, and their names always use forward slashes and include the slashes.  The file named `path/to/file.ext` is literally just the *file*, with that name.  But Git does understand that your computer demands the file-in-folder format, and will convert back and forth as needed.  If Git needs to extract a file whose name is `some/long/file/name.ext`, Git will *create* folders `some`, `some/long`, and so on when it must, all automatically.
>
> The strange side effect of this is that because Git stores only the *files*, not the folders, Git is unable to store an *empty folder*.  This distinction actually occurs in Git's index aka staging area, which we won't get into in any detail, but it explains the problem whose answers are given in [How do I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)
>
> In any case, commits in Git store files, using these path names.  Each commit has a full copy of every file—but the files' contents are stored in a special, Git-ized, read-only, Git-only format in which the contents are *de-duplicated*.  So if a million commits store one particular version of one particular file, there's really only one copy, *shared* between all million commits.  Git can do this kind of sharing because, unlike regular files on your computer, files stored *in* a commit, in Git, literally *can't be changed*.

Going back to the commits now: each commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file (that it had when you, or whoever, made the commit).  But these files are read-only—they literally *can't* have their contents replaced, which is what enables that sharing—and only Git itself can even *read* them.  This makes them useless for actually getting any work done.  They're fine as archives, but no good for real work.

The solution to this problem is simple (and the same as in almost all other version control systems): when you select some commit to work on / with, Git will *extract* the files *from* that commit.  This creates ordinary files, in ordinary folders, in an ordinary area in which you can do your work (whether that's ordinary or substandard or exemplary work—that's all up to you, not to Git ).  What this means is that you do your work in a *working tree* or *work-tree* (Git uses these two terms interchangeably).  More importantly, it means this: **The files you see and work on / with are *not in Git*.**  They may have just been extracted *by* Git, from some commit.  But now they're ordinary files and you use them without Git being aware of what you're doing.

Since Git has extracted these files *into* ordinary folders, you can create new files and/or new folders if you like.  When you run Python programs, Python itself will, at various times, create `__pycache__` folders and stuff `*.pyc` and/or `*.pyo` files into them.  Python does this without Git's knowledge or understanding.

Because these files are *generated by* Python, based on your source, and just used to speed up Python, it's a good idea to *avoid putting them into the commits*.  There's no need to save a permanent snapshot of these files, especially since the format and contents may depend on the specific Python version (e.g., Python 3.7 generates `*.cpython-37.pyc` files, Python 3.9 generates `*.cpython-39.pyc` files, and so on).  So we tell Git two things:

1. Don't complain about the existence of these particular *untracked* files in the working tree.
2. When I use an en-masse "add everything" operation like `git add .`, don't *add* these files to the index / staging-area, so that they won't go into the next commit either.

We generally do this with the (poorly named) `.gitignore` file.  Listing a file name in a `.gitignore` does not make Git *ignore* it; instead, it has the effect of doing the two things I listed here.

This uses the Git-specific term *untracked file*, which has a simple definition that has a complex back-story.  **An untracked file is simply any file in your working tree that is not currently in Git's index (staging area).**  Since we're not going to get into a discussion of Git's index here, we have to stop there for now, but the general idea is that we don't allow the `__pycache__` files to get *into* the index, which keeps them untracked, which keeps Git from committing them, which keeps them from getting into Git's index.  It's all a bit circular here, and if you accidentally *do* get these files into Git's index, *that's* when you need the `git rm -r --cached __pycache__` command.

Since that command is failing, it means you don't have the problem this command is meant to solve.  That's good!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need `__pycache__` files in your git repositories and you'd better to ignore all related files to it by adding `__pycache__/` to your `.gitignore` file.