# Switch between Git branches removing files in another branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Ok, when I switch between branches, and delete a file from one branch it is carried over into the other.

I created a new repo, and pushed to a remote with a file "README.md".

I then switch to a feature branch `git checkout -b feature/hello` and add a file `hello.md`. I add this file `git add hello.md` and commit `git commit -m "hello added"`. I then push this branch and everything is great! `git push origin feature/hello`.

Now I want to switch branch to do some work, and on this feature branch we are going to remove `hello.md` and add a new file `goodbye.md`.

- `git checkout -b feature/goodbye`
- `rm hello.md`
- `git checkout feature/hello`

Now in the `feature/hello` branch I have the files `README.md`  `goodbye.md`.

Why does deleting files in one branch remove them from another?

Comment: It's not deleting the file. You've deleted the file in your working directory then switched branches, the two things aren't really related. If you want to revert that change you need to reset your working directory. Just run `git reset`

Comment: you do need to commit the change before checking out the feature/hello branch.

Comment: Committing wouldn't make much difference. I could Git Stash, but by not committing I still show the problem in this toy version of the problem.

Comment: See also [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246298/7976758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR - changes are *local*, until you *commit* them.**

The file hasn't been removed from the "branch" per se, but rather, its only been removed locally.

When you do `rm [filename]`, you are only removing the file locally. This is different from `git rm [filename]`. Some more details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434449/why-use-git-rm-to-remove-a-file-instead-of-rm) post.

If you check the code you pushed, the file would still be there. In fact, the file is still in the branch -- at least a far as `git` is concerned, since you haven't committed the deletion as a change yet. Its only when you `git add [filename]` that `git` would record the file as deleted. (In fact, even then, you can still change branches and `git commit` the file as deleted in a different branch!)

This is just the way `git` works. You can make changes locally and move between different branches, and then commit the changes to a branch of your choice. (Of course, you may encounter some conflicts along the way, but in principle this works).

In fact, its actually really useful. Say, you are in branch `foo` and you've just made some changes to a few files. But, what you actually wanted to do was make those changes in a *new* branch `bar` which you forgot to create & checkout. Since the changes are still local, you can simply `git checkout -b bar` and commit the changes in branch `bar` as you originally intended.

By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956710/git-recover-deleted-file-where-no-commit-was-made-after-the-delete) post talks about ways to get the deleted file back, in case the `rm` was a mistake.